# How to initialize npm package in vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-package

I trying to use [v-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask) package in vue using npm. i run the `npm install v-mask` as the documentation says, but where exactly I should put in code to initialization? i tried to put it in the main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueMask from 'v-mask'
Vue.use(VueMask);

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

but get an error 'Vue' is not defined. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You try to use Vue 2 plugin with Vue 3. It won't work. You may notice that third-party Vue 2 plugins either have a mention of Vue 3 version on main page, or there's a discussion of Vue 3 in issues.

Answer (score 1):

`v-mask` is built for Vue 2, so you can't use it in Vue 3 (unless you use the [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html), but that's not really intended for third party plugins).

Consider using [`maska`](https://github.com/beholdr/maska), which is a masking library that supports Vue 3:

```bash
npm i -S maska
```

*Example usage:*

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Maska from 'maska'

createApp(App).use(Maska).mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-maska-input-mask?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 0):

try to save the app in a variable and execute `use` for app

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import VueMask from 'v-mask'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueMask)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: now it shows blank page and console gives and error: "Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is undefined"

Comment: @ligwol ok, try to keep a return value from `createApp` and after that use `use`

I updated the original message

Comment: @ligwol hmmmm,  Estus Flask was right. It's not an incompatible library for `Vue3`. 

But you can try to migrate it like here https://alvarosaburido.dev/blog/how-to-migrate-your-library-from-vue2-to-vue3